# Connection to Google Virtual Machine via RDP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, rdp

I find it absurd: from Google 0 support, no phone support, no email support and no chat support.
Even if mine is a free trial, there should be a minimum of minimum support, or not?

However, I hope to find a solution here:

After creating a Windows Virtual Machine on Google Cloud Platform I tried to connect with it via the RDP (Remote Desktop Connection) app. It always replies that the password is incorrect, even though I am 100% sure that the password is correct. I tried with the login credentials created with the VM, and it doesn't work, then I tried with the login credentials of my old Microsoft Account and that also doesn't work. Finally, in order not to miss anything, I also tried those from Google ... but nothing!

Of course in the Firewall I checked the box to allow RDP to access TCP Port 3389 and then I updated the VM

Comment: There should be no need to adjust the firewall, ```default-allow-rdp``` rule is created on every project. Besides it wouldn't say the password is incorrect. It may take up to 10 minutes for a Windows machine to be ready even if it says it's running. Then you can set the password using triangle next to 'RDP' link. Have you tried methods listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-windows#remote-desktop-connection-app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it may take some minutes for Windows VMs to be ready. After the VM has finished booting, which may take a few minutes, you could confirm its state using one of the [following methods](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp#instance_ready).
By using Serial port 1, Serial port 2 or VM screenshot you will ensure the services up and running correctly.

Each Compute Engine Windows instance must have a local password set if it is not already on a domain or custom image. Once you have confirmed the services, you can check your Windows instance password by [connecting to the VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-windows#connecting_to_the_windows_sac) through the Google Cloud CLI command-line tool or Cloud Console.

If you still have issues connecting, try [creating or resetting the password](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/generating-credentials)

Comment: Please read "[Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)". Links rot, then break, and when they do the question won't make sense. Instead, quote the pertinent information in your answer, then give credit to the information.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all!

I solved it by resetting the Password. Most likely I was wrong between a zero and an O. They are characters very very similar to each other and should be distinguished better, perhaps the zero with a slash, and then I noticed another somewhat confusing situation. When I reset the password it automatically displayed the Username I have with the Google Account, while when I created the VM Instance it asked me to enter a different Username (I think).

So there is a bit of confusion !!!